# How to save List that implements Interface on onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have in my `Activity`  :

```
List<IntManager> mt;
this.mt = new ArrayList<IntManager>();
```

Inside the `mt` list I have Objects that implement `IntManager` Interface, but they are let say type of `Point` (my custom class)

Now I want to save the `this.mt` in the `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` and restore it on `onRestoreInstanceState`

How should I save it? Do `IntManager` have to implement `Parcelable` or my custom class `Point` ? or any other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both `IntManager` and any member fields it uses would have to implement `Parcelable` so they could be saved in the `Bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do it by implementing Parcelable and save them to the bundle

or you could use a Json serializer to seriazlize the list of custom objects to a json string and save the string to the bundle. For example, using GSon you could do it this way

```
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<IntManager>>(){}.getType();
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   String json = new Gson().toJson(mt, type);
   outState.putString("message", json);
}
```

and you can restore the instancestate from bundle

```
List<IntManager> test=new Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString("message"), type);
```

hope this helps..

Comment: When I restoring it I get an `ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap>` and not `ArrayList<IntManager>` as I saved on `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: check my updated answer. Use the type while serializing and restoring(deserializing)..